# Add property to interface typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm working on an Angular Project and created this interface to be able to show some data:

```
export interface UserData {
  name: string,
  vorname: string,
  strasse: string,
  plz: string,
  ort: string,
  handynummer: string,
  telefonnummer: string,
}
```

If I want to show add more Data in my database, i would have to add these datapoint to this interface, is there a way to create a interface dynamically, or create it in the Components Constructor?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. An interface describes how some object looks like. If your object has more properties, and you want to use them, then add those properties to the interface.

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to do this in my database, not in the code. This way, if I want to add datapoints, I dont have to change code at multiple locations, but only have to add a property in my database

Comment: I have no idea how Angular is related to your database. I don't know what you mean by datapoint, either. I have the feeling that you would like to add sole column in a database table, and have all the rest of the code magically doing something useful with that new column, without even knowing what it's for, what its name is, or whatever. That won't work.

Comment: If you have a database your front-end should communicate with it with by a back-end. There are code generators that can generate from BE endpoints the model classes on you front-end side.

If it's used swagger on BE side you can easily do that:
https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-openapi-gen

Answer (score 127):

You cannot dynamically change / create an interface as it is just a static value, used for structural type checking by the Typescript compiler.

However, if you need all the properties on that interface and an additional property, you can do a few things:

#### Use [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces)

You can also use `extends` to create a new interface for this specific case.

```
interface ExtendedUserData extends UserData {
 someOtherProperty: string
}
```

#### Use [`Intersection types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)

This may be close to the sort of "dynamic" behavior you're looking for. Say you have a property that needs to be an object with all the properties of `UserData` and an additional `extraProperty`.

You can type it like this.

```
fancyUserData: UserData & { extraProperty: string }
```

With intersection types you can add properties ad hoc.

#### Usage in Angular

In order to use these types in angular, you can create a generic type on your component that would look something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example'
  template: `<h1>example</h1>`
})
export class ExampleComponent<T extends UserData> {}
```

Now you can have data of type T which must have all of the `UserData` properties, then add whatever other properties you'd like.

So in short, no you can't really build dynamic types, and definitely not in the component's constructor. However, you can use the methods I mentioned above to extend and mold your interfaces on an as needed basis.

Comment: i want a behaviour such that there are already class with set of properties and used as type e.g test: TestClass but i need to use all those properties along with runtime properties for particular component since TestClass has been used at multiple places will `TestClass & { extraProperty: string }` will do the trick and is it a good approch too?

Comment: If you add the extra property during runtime only, you may need to use `fancyUserData: UserData & { extraProperty?: string }` to avoid compile time problems about `extraProperty` not existing after the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

To add a property you can define the same interface again and add the additional properties:

```
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
}

interface SquareConfig {
  name: string;
}

let c: SquareConfig = {name:'jack', color:'blue'}
console.log(c) // {"name": "jack", "color": "blue"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new property to an interface by creating a new type like that:

```
export type userDataExtended: UserData & { extraProperty: string }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**